# PHP not executing in Non-native iOS app in Xcode using phoneGap

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, cordova

I am creating an iOS app in html5/css3/javascript implementation using phoneGap. I am trying to connect to a mysql database using PHP, however any PHP script I run on the iOS simulator on Xcode doesn't get executed, it just displays the script instead. I have apache/mysql/php installed and can execute pages stored in the localhost fine, but is there a way for the PHP to work in the iOS simulator in xCode?

Sorry I am very new to this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Simply: No. Build your service on your own server and call the `url` from `objective-c`. Send information in `json` or `xml`.

Comment: You can't use PHP in a PhoneGap App as it's just html/css/javascript.  That said though, you can make an ajax call to a php file on a server...